# How to generate dynamic list in android based on entries from database

Tags: android, database, layout

I want to generate a list from a table in my database. That list should contain all rows of *one* column i.e table: `Contact` column name: `contact_name`. Next I want to show all of the contact_names. But each value should be click-able. When a user clicks on it, it should print in next activity the `contact_name`, `contact_address` etc.

I am new in android. So all help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) or [`CursorAdapter`](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/)